# Save KeplerGL to html with data urls instead of embedded data

Tags: python, kepler.gl

Let's say I want to export a Kepler map but I don't want the data embedded in the html file, I want the browser to download the layers from alternate URLs. Is that possible?

I can put URLs in the data dictionary like this...

```
mymap.save_to_html(data={'Tracts':"https://someplace/tracts.json",
                    'Mines':"https://someplace/stuff.json",
                    'Plants':"https://someplace/flowers.json"}, 
                  file_name="kepmap2.html")
```

but then when I load the file in my browser, in the console, I see an error that the data isn't a valid csv. I see in the source/network tab that it isn't downloading the files. It's erroring out because the url isn't a csv.

```
    function S(e, t) {
        var n, r;
        if ("string" == typeof e) {
            var a = (0,
            u.csvParseRows)(e);
            if (!Array.isArray(a) || a.length < 2)
                throw new Error("process Csv Data Failed: CSV is empty");
            r = a[0],
            n = a.slice(1)
```

This is where it errors because `e` is the url.  The next bit of that code is

```
        } else
            Array.isArray(e) && e.length && (n = e,
            r = t,
            Array.isArray(r) || (r = e[0],
            n = e.slice(1)));
```

so there's some thought to accept something other than a csv but I don't know js so other than seeing that it'll take a js Array, I'm lost.